# Make bands surrounding nodes with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw,
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{entity} = [rectangle, draw, text centered]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \matrix [row sep= 2em, column sep= 2em] {
      & \node [block] (a) {A}; & \\
      \node [block] (b) {B}; & & \node [block] (c) {C};\\
      & \node [block] (d) {D}; & \\
      \node [block] (e) {E}; & & \\
    };
  \end{scope}

  \node [entity, fit= (a)] {};
  \node [entity, fit= (b) (c)] {};
  \node [entity, fit= (d)] {};
  \node [entity, fit= (e)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Suppose that each of the nodes is a different step. Each of them are part of a bigger stage, which is signaled by surrounding them with the `entity`s. How can I make sure that each `entity` is:

- the *exact same width*
- centered with each other
- have no separation between them?

Since I will later colorize them, the `entity`s will be `[on background layer]`.

Comment: `text width`, `text height`, `anchor=center`. The last is probably best done in the matrix with `node distance` or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution consists in using some anchors on `matrix` node to define convenient rectangles on a background layer.

First of all I've changed deprecated `tikzstyle` by `tikzset`. You can read about it in [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

The `matrix` has been changed to a `matrix of nodes` (you need `matrix` library) and adjusted matrix `inner sep=1em`. This way all layers will present a similar space around inner nodes.

```
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, inner sep=1em, row sep= 2em, column sep= 2em, nodes={block}]
```

I've preserved original nodes names with syntax `|(A)| A`, if you don't need it just write `A` as node contents.

```
|(B)| B & &|(C)| C\\
```

As `inner` nodes and `matrix` anchor are not directly related. Two auxiliar anchors are defined:

```
\path (M.north) -- coordinate[pos=.25] (aux1) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux2) (M.south);
```

And finally these anchors are used to draw and fill four bands on a `background` layer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    block/.style={draw, text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em},
    entity/.style={draw, text centerd}
]

  \begin{scope}
    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, inner sep=1em, row sep= 2em, column sep= 2em, nodes={block}] {
      & A & \\
      B & & C\\
      & D & \\
      E & & \\
    };
  \end{scope}

    \path (A.north) -- coordinate[pos=.25] (aux1) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux2) (A.south);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[fill=green!30] (A.north west) rectangle (aux1-|A.east);
  \draw[fill=red!30] (A.west|-aux1) rectangle (A.east);
  \draw[fill=blue!30] (A.west) rectangle (aux2-|A.east);
  \draw[fill=orange!30] (A.west|-aux2) rectangle (A.south east);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]